# Angular Directive Two-Way Binding Issue

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-directive

I am creating a custom input directive for some added features.

```
app.directive('myTextInput', [
    function () {
        var directive = {};
        directive.restrict = 'A';
        directive.scope = {
            textModel: '='
        };
        directive.link = function ($scope, element, attrs) {
            // FUnctionality
        };
        directive.template = '<input ng-model="textModel" type="text">';
    return directive;
}]);
```

and used the isolated scope property `textModel` for two way binding.
And the parent scope HTML is:

```
<div my-text-input text-model="myScopeVariable"></div>
<span>TYPED : {{myScopeVariable}}</span>
```

The controller scope has variable `$scope.myScopeVariable="";` defined.

When i do this.
what ever typed in the directive input is able to print in the `<span>` tag.
Which tells it is updating.

The issue is.

in the parent scope. i have a method that will execute on a button click.

```
$scope.doSomething = function(){
    console.log($scope.myScopeVariable);
};
```

On click on the button. the log is empty. which is supposed to be what is typed in the directive input.

**THIS IS STRANGE**

Now if define the scope variable as

```
$scope.myScopeVariable = {key:''};
```

and use in HTML as

```
<div my-text-input text-model="myScopeVariable.key"></div>
<span>TYPED : {{myScopeVariable.key}}</span>
```

then it is working every where. Even in the previously said function `doSomething()`.

Any idea what happening here ?

Comment: Hrmm, I try to replicate the problem, but it looks fine to me. http://plnkr.co/edit/SyRPmIvxvnAw7CPBv2NJ?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

This is happen because `myScopeVariable` contain value as **String**. 
So if you change the value of from textbox of directive. It wont be reflected.

And in second method, you are referring Object. so whenever you change value of object , its relevant watch method is called. And value will be updated.

Answer (score 0):

`my-text-input` is a directive, so he has his own scope, so the model `myScopeVariable` is not watch by the parent.

try with this :

`<div my-text-input text-model="$parent.myScopeVariable"></div>
<span>TYPED : {{myScopeVariable}}</span>`

It's not the best practice but it might works.